# Does scrapy-crawlera handle a 429 status code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, crawlera

Wondering if anyone knows if scrapy-crawlera middleware handles the 429 status code when using scrapy, or if I need to implement my own retry logic?

I can't seem to find it documented anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: **NO**, The [scrapy-crawlera](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-crawlera) Middleware doesn't handle `429` status, it actually doesn't "handle" any status, it just handles communication between Crawlera and Scrapy.

Now, about [`Crawlera`](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera), they do handle status `429` by default, meaning that when they get a `429` response status, they will mark it as a ban and retry the same request.

If Crawlera didn't succeed after several retries, it will return a `503` status to the client (Scrapy in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend list of retry codes with:

```
from scrapy.settings.default_settings import RETRY_HTTP_CODES
```

(check documentation here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-RETRY_HTTP_CODES)

And then in you spider:

```
custom_settings = {
    'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': RETRY_HTTP_CODES + [429],
}
```